# How to create line chart in PowerBI when the value is a text (Ok, Incorrect)?

Tags: powerbi, percentage, powerbi-desktop, linechart

[image]

Hi everyone,

I want to plot the line chart above in PowerBI based on the data that I have in column A,B and C. The challenge that I have is that the `Values` of the line chart only able to show as `Percent of grand total` instead of `Percent of row/column total`.

I'm still new to PowerBI, not sure any new measure that I can use to create the line chart above.

[image]

The line chart above is what I'm able to create in PowerBI, may I know what should I do to change the y-axis into percentage (percentage of OK for Mar + percentage of Incorrect for Mar = 100%) ? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by grand total? for all month? or month wise?

Comment: In month wise. Basically I want the line chart able to show the percentage of `OK` and `Incorrect` for each month, exactly the same as what I shown in the first screenshot. The percentage of `OK` + the percentage of `Incorrect` will be equal to 100% for each month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create these below 3 measure-

```
total_student = DISTINCTCOUNT(your_table_name[Name])
```

```
ok_% = 

VAR OK_COUNT = COUNTROWS(
    FILTER(
        your_table_name,
        your_table_name[Answer] = "ok"
    )
)

RETURN (OK_COUNT/your_table_name[total_student])
```

```
incorrect_% = 

VAR incorrect_count = COUNTROWS(
    FILTER(
        your_table_name,
        your_table_name[Answer] = "incorrect"
    )
)

RETURN (incorrect_count/your_table_name[total_student])
```

Now **convert last 2 measure as %** and create your chart. Here below I have created everything for first 2 month from your sample data-

[image]

**Note** Your Month field need proper ordering for correct output.